# How to redirect to a particular link if checkbox is checked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

How to redirect to a particular link if checkbox is checked using javascript?

I am doing this but its not working for me..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="yousendit" id="yousendit" value="1" onselect="return yousendit();"/>

<script type=javascript>
function yousendit()
{
        if(document.getElementById('yousendit').checked== "checked")
        {
            window.location='https://www.yousendit.com/dropbox?dropbox=mydomain';
            return false;
        }
        return true;

}
</script>
```

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some problems with your source. Here is the working version:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="yousendit" id="yousendit" value="1" onclick="return yousendit();"/>
<script>
function yousendit(){
    if(document.getElementById('yousendit').checked){
        window.location='https://www.yousendit.com/dropbox?dropbox=mydomain';
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
</script>
```

Changes:

- `onclick` instead of `onselect`
- checkboxes' `checked` property is boolean

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe `onselect` is a valid event for a checkbox, but I may be wrong on that.

Regardless, this works.

```
document.getElementById('yousendit').onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked==true)
        alert('checked'); // Or in your case, window.location = 'whatever.html';
}​​​​​​
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Tm6q6/

Answer (score 3):

**use this code**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="xyz.php"
    name="checket"
    onClick="if (this.checked) { window.location = this.value; }">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using onselect use onclick event.

and instead of writing

if(document.getElementById('yousendit').checked== "checked")

write  if(document.getElementById('yousendit').checked)