# Redirect when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, checkbox

**Please, my question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690419/how-to-redirect-to-a-particular-link-if-checkbox-is-checked-using-javascript) question.**

I need to redirect user to the new page when he clicks on span with checkbox inside, but I still can't figure out how to do this because when you click on span with checkbox, it submiting the form and user redirects to the wrong page.

Here is my html:

```
<span class="niceCheck nstcheck active" onclick="check_checked()">
    <input name="p[473][]" value="Stolovaia" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</span>
```

And here is how I'm trying to redirect user:

```
function check_checked() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            var queryPart = window.location.href.indexOf('?');
            var baseUrl   = window.location.href.substr(0, queryPart);
            window.location.href = baseUrl;
            return false;
        } else {
            var lastSlash = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/');
            var baseUrl   = window.location.href.substr(0, lastSlash);
            window.location.href = baseUrl;
            return false;
        }
}
```

I also tried to do `onclick="check_checked(); return false;"` and `window.location.replace`, but still no progress.

When I'm on:

```
http://m.resolute.loc/shop/category/dlia-doma/stoly/dereviannye/vkakuykomnatu-stolovay-filtr
```

and after clicking on checkbox my url is (this is stange, but this site is adding $_GET to url by his own so I'm trying to cut it and redirect to clear page):

```
http://m.resolute.loc/shop/category/dlia-doma/stoly/dereviannye?order=rating&user_per_page=18&lp=1199&rp=74155
```

but my baseUrl is equals to:

```
http://m.resolute.loc/shop/category/dlia-doma/stoly/dereviannye
```

Comment: dont use inline javascript/ onclick attributes

Comment: Clicking a span (which should be a `label` here instead in the first place) or a checkbox does not submit a form on its own; if that happens, then you must have additional JS code in place, that you kept from us.

Comment: @Alex, what do you mean?

Comment: @mrVG I mean, dont use `onclick` attributes

Comment: He means to say you should use eventHandlers whenever possible, but this is not the issue here. What CBroe wrote is the reason you have issues

Comment: @CBroe, I can `alert()` or `console.log()` in this function but location.href doesn't work.

Comment: @mrVG try to attack the problem at hand here, using onclick or using eventHandlers, all the same wouldn't solve the issue. I agree with you and this is wrong, but it is not contributing to the issue at hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to a particular link if checkbox is checked using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690419/how-to-redirect-to-a-particular-link-if-checkbox-is-checked-using-javascript)

Comment: @AkhileshSingh, no, my question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in **completely** different way. I decided to add my checking code to `on submit` action, like that:

```
$('form#catalogForm').on('submit', function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
        var queryPart = window.location.href.indexOf('?');
        var baseUrl   = window.location.href.substr(0, queryPart);
    } else {
        var lastSlash = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/');
        var baseUrl   = window.location.href.substr(0, lastSlash);
    }
    window.location.href = baseUrl;
    return false;
}
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a surprising number of issues for so little code there...

Firstly, no need for all that `lastIndexOf('/')` and `substr` nonsense, just set `location.href = '..';` and the browser will take you up one folder with ease - and it won't break in the edge case where you're already at the root ;)

Next up, your code won't fire at all if I <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the checkbox and hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle it. Instead, you should use a `<label>` to wrap the box, and an `onChange` event handler on the checkbox itself.

And finally, the root problem: your function has `return false;`, but the handler isn't propagating that. You would need `onChange="return check_checked();"` to pass the value on.

Comment: I tried `onChange="return check_checked();"`, but it still submiting the form instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

you must to catch the event and prevent default, also I think you are using the wrong we to redirect with javascript.

Pass the event to the onclick function:

```
<span class="niceCheck nstcheck active" onclick="return check_checked(event)">
    <input name="p[473][]" value="Stolovaia" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</span>
```

Modify your js code:

```
function check_checked(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var lastSlash = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/');
    var baseUrl   = window.location.href.substr(0, lastSlash);
    window.location= baseUrl;

    return false;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I'm sorry, but It still submiting the form instead of redirecting to baseUrl.

Comment: I have updated my response.

Comment: You also probably made a mistake in `e.preventDefault(;)`, it should be `e.preventDefault();`, but I still can't redirect.

Comment: Yes, is a mistake, sorry, please can you provide some piece more representative of your code?

Comment: I've updated my code and I showed what url I'm receiving and what url I need.